# how to tell gnuplot not to add an offset to x values when doing a plot with two y axes?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

My data file looks like:

> 0   12.6    303.1   3.4577387486
>
> 120 10.5    278.9   2.8814489572
>
> ...
>
> 640 9.45    301.3   2.5933040615

My code looks like:

```
set xlabel "Tiempo (min)"
set ylabel "Corriente en el anillo (mA)"
set y2label "Flujo (fotones/s)"
set ytics nomirror
set y2tics
set tics out
set autoscale  y
set autoscale y2
plot 'tan_time_curr_flux.dat' using 1:3 lc rgb 'black' pt 6 lw 2 w lp axes x1y1 title "Corriente", 'tan_time_curr_flux.dat' using 1:4 lc rgb 'blue' pt 5 lw 2 w lp axes x2y2 title "Flujo"
```

My plot looks like:
[image]

As you can see, there is a little offset, in x, between respective data points. It is more clear as x grows. For example the actual last point for flux (flujo) is 640,2.59. But the plot shows that point at 700, 2.59. How can I tell gnuplot not to add any offset to the second (blue) line?

Thanks a lot! :)

Ps If I plot time (col. 1) vs either flux (col. 4) or current (col. 3)...
The values for x stay normal. (i.e. There is no offset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's a bug.

However, simply use `axes x1y2` for your second plot, since you only have one x-value.

Comment: I think it was that ..`axes x1y2` make the plot as it should be. Thanks!